# A bit of automation?

Tags: drupal-rules

I'd like to automate couple of settings in my contact list and I was wondering can these be done without writing special extensions or Drupal modules:

1. Couple of people qualify to be a Head Coach of the Club, so when the time comes one of them will be selected via Relationships. Can I remove an existing relationship from other person when new person gets selected? So there's only 1 head coach in each club?
2. There's 2 types of players - Junior and Senior (I have this as a custom select field) - when a player turns 18 or when I create a new one via Webform, the type is automatically selected for the right age?

I tried Drupal Rules, Civirules but I didn't find an easy way to do it so no manual work is necessary...

Answer (score 2):

1/ You can do this in a Drupal Webform so that the original coach has their relationship expired

2/ we did some work for another age-based organisation to ensure that only the valid membership type was available based on the Date of Birth. It isn't something that I could just 'share' but if it helps you and you have a bit of budget we could probably extract what you need fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Without writing code (an extension or CiviRules conditions), I think your only bet is to use smart groups for Junior/Senior players.  I don't think there's any way to remove the head coach relationship automatically without code.